# Is there a way to clear roaming settings of a mailbox from Outlook UI?

Tags: outlook-web-addins

We are building an Outlook addin in which we save some user states into the [RoamingSettings](https://dev.office.com/reference/add-ins/outlook/RoamingSettings).

We understand that calling [RoamingSettings.remove()](https://dev.office.com/reference/add-ins/outlook/RoamingSettings) can delete certain settings from the addin code. But we are looking for a way to clear these settings from the Outlook UI so that our QA are able to reset the state easily.

Comment: Outlook UI doesn't provide anything like this. The quickest way would be uninstall and install back add-on.

Comment: Like Slava mentions, there is no Outlook UI to achieve this. Like you mention, you can use .Remove() to delete settings.